# Ruby on Rails Seed Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I am Ruby/Rails newbie. I am currently learning about the Rails console and databases using Rake and the seeds.rb file.

I am supposed to:

- Add a post with a unique title and body to seeds.rb.
- Before creating a unique post, verify it exists in the database. Only
  seed the post if it doesn't.
- Run rake db:seed a couple times, start your Rails console and confirm
  that your unique post has only been seeded once.
- Repeat to create a unique comment and confirm that it is also only
  seeded once.

Honestly I don't know how to start working on this. I am supposed to add a post using the rails console or directly from the seeds.rb file? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Run rake db:seed a couple times" you only would ever run this once.

Comment: "Before creating a unique post, verify it exists in the database. Only seed the post if it doesn't." This makes no sense. You would seed the DB when you create it. In-fact rake db:setup runs rake db:seed. Seeds provide a concept of pre-populating the database with application dependent data or "sample data"

Comment: The individual who gave you those instructions should not ever be giving anyone instructions.

Comment: @jBeas The reason the tutorial is asking the OP to run `rake db:seed` more than once is to test that seeding is idempotent.  You are correct that you'd not normally seed more than once.

Comment: You are supposed to use the seed file to create the post, and the console to verify that it has only been created once.

Answer (score 6):

Despite the intention of `seed`-ing - that this is meant to be run once, to populate the database - there is no technical constrain preventing you from running `rake db:seed` command couple times. Even without cleaning/recreating your database.

In that case, try following code for *db/seeds.rb*

```
post_atrributes = [
  { title: "Sample Title 1", body: "Sample body 1" },
  { title: "Sample Title 2", body: "Sample body 2" },
  { title: "Sample Title 3", body: "Sample body 3" },
]

post_attributes.each do |attributes|
  Post.create(attributes) unless Post.where(attributes).first
end
```

First of all, we're defining an array of attributes for each `Post`, to be created.

Later, we're iterating through that array (with `post_attributes.each do |attributes|`), and trying create a new `Post`, unless one with specified attributes found.

In Rails, there is quite fancy method [`first_or_create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create), which does exactly that - queries database for specified attributes (`where(attributes)`), and if nothing found - creates new record based on provided attributes.

```
post_atrributes = [
  { title: "Sample Title 1", body: "Sample body 1" },
  { title: "Sample Title 2", body: "Sample body 2" },
  { title: "Sample Title 3", body: "Sample body 3" },
]

post_attributes.each do |attributes|
  Post.where(attributes).first_or_create
end
```

At this point, you can "seed" the database with `rake db:seed` and check what is stored in database (after running `rails console`) by:

```
Post.all.map(&:title)
```

Assuming you had empty database before running `rake db:seed`, it should contain only 3 `Post`s. The ones specified with attributes in `post_attributes`.

Now, if you try to modify your *db/seeds.rb* again, adding an attributes for one more `Post`:

```
post_atrributes = [
  { title: "Sample Title 1", body: "Sample body 1" },
  { title: "Sample Title 2", body: "Sample body 2" },
  { title: "Sample Title 3", body: "Sample body 3" },
  { title: "Another Post", body: "WOW!" },
]

post_attributes.each do |attributes|
  Post.where(attributes).first_or_create
end
```

After running `rake db:seed`, and checking in console:

```
Post.all.map(&:title)
```

You can see, that only one new `Post` has been created. The one with title "Another Post".

In your question I understood, that when creating new `Post`, both attributes - `title` and `body` have be unique, so if you try to perform the same for attributes like:

```
post_atrributes = [
  { title: "Sample Title 1", body: "Sample body 1" },
  { title: "Sample Title 1", body: "Sample body 2" },
]
```

This will create two separate `Post`s, because they have different `body` attributes defined.

For `Comment`s you can do similar thing.

Again, as jBeas mentioned earlier - `seed`-ing has different purpose, but if this is only exercise to play with `ActiveRecord` - this is one of ways how you can tackle the problem.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

`Seeding` is the process of populating a database with data.

There are two methods used to accomplish this.

You can use `ActiveRecord Migrations`

```
class AddInitialProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    5.times do |i|
      Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
    end
  end

  def down
    Product.delete_all
  end
end
```

Or you can store it in a separate `seeds.rb` file

```
5.times do |i|
  Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
end
```

afterwards, run `rake db:seed`

Source

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

Comment: As Darkmouse showed you, seeds.rb is a normal ruby file where you can put any code you want. So you can also put code which tests whether a post exists or not.

But if you really want to use uniqueness validations I suggest to create a Post model and a Comment model.